# No matching version found for gatling@^2.0.0

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am trying to run the Node Unblocker web proxy bit when I try to run the command "npm install" I get this error:

```
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for gatling@^2.0.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

I have downloaded the Gatling package, installed Java 8 JDK, and have even tried to get an old version of Gatling. Node Unblocker can be found here: https://github.com/nfriedly/nodeunblocker.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatling npm package you need for this nodeunblocker has absolutely nothing to do with Java nor the [Gatling load test tool](https://gatling.io/).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do anything wrong, and it should work if you try it again today.

The gatling v2 update didn't get published to npm initially due to a CI failure, but the nodeunblocker website update *did* get published to GitHub. So they were mismatched for a short while, leading to the error you encountered.